# Issue with Storybook autogenerating docs/prop description for a react component

Tags: babeljs, jsdoc, storybook

Mine is a older repo (think webpack 3.*). I added storybook to the repo and modified a few of the webpack rules for my `.scss` files to load properly.

I can get the Storybook controls to load properly. But the `ArgsTable` in the docs section does not respect my comments that I gave in `propTypes`.

Here is my component - `NewPill.js`

```
import styles from './NewPill.scss';

const NewPill = props => {
    const { text, color } = props;
    return <span className={`${styles.newPill} ${color}`}> {text} </span>;
};

NewPill.propTypes = {
    /**
     * Denotes the text of the pill
     */
    text: PropTypes.string,
    /**
     * Denotes the color of the pill
     */
    color: PropTypes.string,
};

export default NewPill;
```

Here is my story - `NewPill.stories.js`

```
import NewPill from './NewPill';

export default {
    title: 'Components/NewPill',
    component: NewPill,
};

const Template = args => {
        console.log(NewPill.__docgenInfo); // Gives me undefined
    return <NewPill {...args} />;
};

export const FirstStory = Template.bind({});
FirstStory.args = {
    text: 'Pill Text',
    color: 'blue',
};
```

And this is the output,

[image]

The workaround is obviously to add `argTypes` to the story itself.

```
FirstStory.argTypes = {
    text: {
           control: { type: 'text' },
           description: 'Denotes the text of the pill',
        }
    color: 'blue',
};
```

But it'd be nice if the storybook system grabs that info from the original component itself. Is there a way to see if the `babel-plugin-react-docgen` worked? I followed their instructions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-docgen) with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same issue. The problem is in version you use.
Downgrading Storybook to v `6.3.0` solved the issue in my case.

PS: It was mandatory to downgrade packages one by one (smth like that `npx sb@6.3.0 init` doesn't work as expected).